# Exception while sending message to Azure Service Bus Topics

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

While sending messages to Azure Service Bus Topics from existing .Net application, I am getting following exception

> The type initializer for 'Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Core.ClientLibraryInformation' threw an exception.
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The above is working fine in a new .Net Core application. I am unable to find out what is wrong.

Comment: This is caused by assembly conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually update the references. When I did this, the method started working fine.

Comment: What references did you update? Thanks.